# Converting Elm expressions to Strings

Tags: elm

Is there a way to convert an Elm expression to a string representation of its code?

e.g.

```
sourceString : a -> String

sourceString (1 + 3) == "(1 + 3)"
```

I haven't heard of macros in Elm, but perhaps there is still a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot do this in Elm. The function will only have access to the computed value, which will be `4` in this case. In all the languages I know where this is possible (Rust, Elixir, all the Lisp dialects), it's done using macros and Elm does not have that feature as of the current version, 0.18.